# Changing the background color when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript

I need to use .onclick method to change the color of a link when clicked but the problem is when i click on another link the first link color don't return back to the original color, so ny suggestions?

Comment: You dont need javascript for this. Its CSS. `a:focus` e.g. `a:focus { color: red; }`

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read the following article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I also believe a CSS solution is better, but if you really want an onClick method, you can try the following:

```js
const one = document.getElementById("one");
const two = document.getElementById("two");

function updateOne() {
  reset();
  one.style.color = "red";
}

function updateTwo() {
  reset();
  two.style.color = "red"
 }
 
function reset() {
  one.style.color = "blue";
  two.style.color = "blue";
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<a href="#" onClick="updateOne()" id="one">Link One</a>
<br>
<a href="#" onClick="updateTwo()" id="two">Link Two</a>
</body>
</html>
```